# Pattern creation of collectibles - LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working on a LibGdx running game.I have collectibles/coins in the game.
I have created a coin array,and spawned it throughout the game.

To improve the play,I want to make patterns of coins.Like 2 coins or 3 coins together , coins in vertical or diagonal arrangements etc.
I tried to implement this,but found it a difficult task as a fresher.

Please suggest me some code to implement patterns like triangle with an array of objects.
Like this:triangle with 3 coins in equal distance:
[image]

My coin array and method are included here:
I am adding new coins on the basis of last coin passes a particular distance on the screen.

```
Array<Coin> coins = new Array<Coin>();

private void createCoin() {

    coinObj = objectFactory.createCoin(CoinEnum.random());
    coinObj.isCollided = false;
    coins.add(coinObj);

}

private void spawnCoin() {

    if (coins.size == 0) {
        createCoin();
    } else {
        Coin c = coins.peek();

        if (c.getY() > (Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT / 8))
            createCoin();
    }
    // remove out of screen coins
    if (coins.size > 0) {
        Coin cc = coins.first();
        if (cc.getY() > Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT) {
            coins.removeValue(cc, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Also hope someone can tell me the mistakes in my approach if any!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "someone can tell me the mistakes in my approach" what isn't working?

Comment: If you think about the problem you present here just for one minute. What are the patterns you want to create? Write them down, not just an abstract idea of a pattern. Write down the pattern. Draw it. What are the rules of the patterns. Are the coins at a set distance from each other? If you do not know the pattern you want you can't expect anyone else to tell you how to make it. Edit your post with an illustration of the pattern you want to create and an explanation of the rules of the pattern.

Comment: `createCoin()` method is also worth sharing.

Comment: Code is working well.I mentioned if any.Thank you.-@1blustone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to model the `CoinPattern`:
- What is a `CoinPattern`?
It is just a pattern, describing an arrangement of multiple coins.
- What do I need to describe it?
As it is just a pattern, you don't need no `Coin`s yet.
In my opinion, a list of `Point`s (or `Vector2`) should be enough.
Each of these `Point`s could describe the relative `Position` of the `Object` (in your case `Coin`) inside the `Pattern`.

Now you could create constants for your `Pattern`s. The triangle could look something like this:

```
public static final PATTERN_TRIANGLE = new Vector2[] {
    new Vector2(0,0),
    new Vector2(1,0),
    new Vector2(0,1),
};
```

Then you could create a method `spawnPattern(Vector2[] pattern, int x, int y)`. This method should then create a `Coin` for every `Vector2` in the `pattern`.
The position of each `Coin` could be calculated like this:

```
int posX = x + pattern[i].x;
int posY = y + pattern[i].y;
```

Note, that using this methode, the positions of the `Coin`s are relative to the lower, left corner of the `Pattern` position.